# Relative routing in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly, relative-path, blazor-routing

I'm new with Blazor and C#, and I'm trying to figure out how navigate using relative path.
Suppose I have this structure:

```
Index:    /
Page2:    /pageTwo
Page3:    /pageThree
PageFour: /pageThree/pageFour
```

I'd like to navigate among these pages using relative path.

I tried to navigate using NavigationManager:

From index I can go to pageTwo with `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("pageTwo");`

From Page2 I would like to go to page three, but using following doesn't work:

- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("../pageThree")`
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("../pageThree").AbsoluteUri)`
  I tried
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("~/../pageThree").AbsoluteUri)`
  and page is accessed correctly, but why use ~? (searching for an answer about relative path I found people talking about ~ and I wanted to try)

From Page3 I'd like to go to Page4 but none of my try is working:

- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("./pageFour").AbsoluteUri)`
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("~/./pageFour").AbsoluteUri)`
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("~/pageFour").AbsoluteUri)`
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("pageFour").AbsoluteUri)`
- `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/pageFour").AbsoluteUri)`

I wrote a little program showing my test at https://blazorfiddle.com/s/9lnhs40p

Comment: Sorry, but you are working with routing not physical files. So you have to provide the exact route. What you could do is create a static class with constants (routes). E.x: `public static class Routes  { public const string PageOne = "/pageOne"; ... }`

Comment: So, there's no way to use relative uri? from this address `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.toabsoluteuri?view=aspnetcore-7.0` it looks to me that ToAbsoluteUri should calculate what I need... but it doesnt work.
I could use constants, but if routing is complex (ie /listOfProduct/{id}/lostOfChildren/{otherId}9 the navigation with relative path from a page to the other can help, i think (hope I've been clear)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use ./ pattern.

Just use / as below

```cs
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/pageTwo");
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/pageThree");
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/pageFour");

NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/logout");
```

Comment: Consider putting code inside three backticks (```) for syntax highlighting and better visibility.